# Methods with Different Signatures that Return the Intersection of Two Sets (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist

I created a method that returns the intersection of two sets of values. The thing is that I want to use a different signature that uses only one arrayList within the method and not all of them.

```
public class Group <T>
{     
  ArrayList<T> w = new ArrayList<T>();

  //Here I have the add and remove methods and a method  that returns 
  //false if the item is not in the set and true if it is in the set

  public static ArrayList intersection(Group A, Group B) 
  {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList first = (ArrayList) A.w.clone();
    ArrayList second = (ArrayList) B.w.clone();


    for (int i = 0; i < A.w.size(); i++) 
    {
        if (second.contains(A.w.get(i))) 
        {
            list.add(A.w.get(i));
            second.remove(A.w.get(i));
            first.remove(A.w.get(i));
        }
    }
    return list;
  }
}
```

This is the other method with the different signature. How can I make this method to return the intersection of two sets if the signature is different from the method shown above?

```
public class Group <T>
{
   ArrayList<T> w = new ArrayList<T>();

   public static <T> Group<T> intersection(Group <T> A, Group <T> B)
   {
       Group<T> k= new Group<T>();


     return  k;
    }
}

public class Main
{
     public static void main(String [] args)
     {
         Group<Integer> a1 = new Group<Integer>();
         Group<Integer> b1 = new Group<Integer>();
         Group<Integer> a1b1 = new Group<Integer>();


         //Here I have more codes for input/output 
      }
 }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use raw types, and parameters `A` and `B` should be lowercase.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot overload methods by their return value in Java - you'll have to rename one of them. E.g:

```
public static <T> Group<T> intersectionGroup(Group <T> A, Group <T> B)

public static ArrayList intersectionArrayList(Group A, Group B)
```

Comment: I am not going to integrate both methods. I just want to know how to create a similar method with a different signature.

Comment: @Plrr And I think he answered you--you can't.  Not the way you want to do it.  It just isn't legal in Java.  Sorry.

Comment: @ajb what exactly is "illegal" in Java?

Comment: @Plrr Declaring two methods in the same class with the same name and same parameter types (after generic type erasure).  Even if the result types are different.

Comment: @ajb I am not sure if you misunderstood the question asked, but I never intended to use "both" methods in the same class. I just wanted to know how I could "re-write" the first method differently using a different signature. As for declaring two methods in the same class, I know it is not permissible in Java as you stated before.

Comment: @Plrr I know I'm not the only one who misunderstood.  Both of your `intersection` methods in your question belong to a class named `Group`, so it sure looked like you wanted to declare both in the same class.  Was one of your classes supposed to have a different name?